# How can I bulk update the TTL for existing Route 53 DNS records?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a hosted zone in Amazon Route 53 with over 15k records. I am trying to change the TTL for all these records via a script, but couldn't find much that would help in this case.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't a convenient 'BulkUpdateTTL' API that just takes in a zone ID & an updated TTL value, yes, you can do this programmatically.

You need to use 2 APIs:

1. `ListResourceRecordSets` ([API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ListResourceRecordSets.html), [CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53/list-resource-record-sets.html)) to list the records in your hosted zone
2. `ChangeResourceRecordSets` ([API reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeResourceRecordSets.html), [CLI](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)) to then update the TTL value for each record

For `ListResourceRecordSets`, the API returns at max 300 records at a time. If you're doing this via the CLI, it will [automatically handle pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html) for you and will do the 50 (15,000/300) requests you need behind the scenes before providing you with the result.

If using the SDK, you will need to implement the pagination logic yourself. If there are more pages to obtain, the response will have the `IsTruncated` property set to true. Keep sending requests until this is set to `false`, meaning you have listed all of the records. To display the next set of 300 records, get the values of `NextRecordName`, `NextRecordType`, and `NextRecordIdentifier` (if any) from each response and provide them as the respective values for `StartRecordName`, `StartRecordType`, and `StartRecordIdentifier` for the next `ListResourceRecordSets` call.

For `ChangeResourceRecordSets`, you can update at most [1000 records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/DNSLimitations.html#limits-api-requests) at a time. Populate your `Changes` array with a list of changes to the records you obtained - for each record, specify the `Name`, the desired new `TTL` value and the action as `UPSERT`.

I've been able to find [this script](https://github.com/manuel-sousa/aws-utils/blob/master/updateRoute53.py) from 2016 which looks to be a Python implementation of the above logic - feel free to try the dry run option or run it within a test environment before using it. It may need some tweaking.

The logic remains the same :)